# Is there a way, to

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, time, charts

I am currently working on a project where I have to pick a random file out of 74 CSV files and visualize it using Python and matplotlib. one requirement of the project is that I need to be able to set the time in which the visualization takes place. the only problem is that the animation takes longer than the time I want to set.
This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import os
import random

class AnimationGUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Animation GUI")
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

        # Verzeichnis aus dem Csv Dateien eingelesen werden
        os.chdir('C:\\Users\\hoppel\\Documents\\CSV Profile 2')

        # Einlesen der Csv Datei
        self.number = random.randint(1, 74)
        dateiend = '.csv'
        Datei = str(self.number) + dateiend
        self.Daten = pd.read_csv(Datei, sep=';')
        self.Daten['Uhrzeit'] = pd.to_datetime(self.Daten['Uhrzeit'], format='%H:%M:%S')
        self.max_verbrauch = self.Daten['Verbrauch'].max()

        # GUI-Elemente erstellen
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=root)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Start", command=self.start_animation)
        self.start_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.stop_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=self.stop_animation)
        self.stop_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.duration_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Animationsdauer (Minuten):")
        self.duration_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.duration_entry = ttk.Entry(root)
        self.duration_entry.insert(0, "5")  # Default value
        self.duration_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # Zeitdaten als Label erstellen
        self.time_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Zeitdaten")
        self.time_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.time_data_label = ttk.Label(root, text="")
        self.time_data_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.ani = None

    def plotfunc(self, i):
        index = int(i * len(self.Daten) / self.num_frames)
        window_start = max(index - 15 * 60, 0)
        window_end = min(index, len(self.Daten) - 1)
        window_data = self.Daten.iloc[window_start:window_end]

        self.ax.cla()
        lines, = self.ax.plot(window_data['Uhrzeit'], window_data['Verbrauch'], color='red')
        self.ax.set_xlabel('Zeitraum')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Verbrauch')
        self.ax.set_title('Tagesverbrauch ' + str(self.number))
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, self.max_verbrauch + 30)
        self.ax.set_xlim
        self.ax.set_xticks([]) 
        self.ax.set_facecolor('black')

        # Aktualisieren der Zeitdaten
        current_time = self.Daten.iloc[index]['Uhrzeit']
        self.time_data_label.config(text=current_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

        return [lines]

    def start_animation(self):
        duration_minutes = int(self.duration_entry.get())
        fps = 40
        self.num_frames = int(fps * 60 * duration_minutes)

        if self.ani is None:
            self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.plotfunc, frames=self.num_frames, interval=1000 / fps, blit=True)
        else:
            self.ani.event_source.start()

    def stop_animation(self):
        if self.ani is not None:
            self.ani.event_source.stop()

    
root = tk.Tk()
app = AnimationGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

the csv Datas are organized like that(24 h in seconds):

```
Uhrzeit;Verbrauch
00:00:01;252
00:00:02;252
00:00:03;252
00:00:04;252
00:00:05;252
00:00:06;252
00:00:07;251
00:00:08;251
00:00:09;251
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] to be able to reproduce your issue, also pick a meaningful title for your question and remove the chitchat (go to the point)

Comment: When displaying an animation **while simultaneously rendering it**, the duration of the animation will be influenced by the specifications of the computer your are using to render it. Matplotlib doesn't account for different hardware capabilities, so the animation will take longer than fps * total frames would suggest. If you save the animation, and then play it back, it should have the correct duration, though.

Comment: how do i upload my folder with the csv files for you to reproduce my problem?

Comment: Instead of providing your real data, for a StackOverflow question it is much more interesting to create a dummy dataset similar in structure to your data. E.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'Uhrzeit': [f'{h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}' for h in range(24) for m in range(60) for s in range(60)]}); df['Verbrauch'] = np.random.randint(1, 300, len(df))`